# ArrayList ERROR: same size, containing "null" elements after remove() some of them

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have a `ArrayList` of objects, and sometimes I'm calling `remove()` for deleting some of them.

I noticed some reports of `NullPointerException` in Google Android Developer Console, and finally I disscovered that in some cases, I'm iterating that array to access the objects, and for some reason, after removing some of the objects, the size of the array is still the same, so for example if the array haves 11 elements and I remove the last one, it still haves 11 elements, but the last one contains null, so, as `.size()` returns 11, it's gives `nullpointerexception` after trying to access the null object contained in the last position.

Why it's happening this? how can this be avoided?

EDIT: Before iterating, and after removing, I'm merging three arrays with "addAll()" into a mixed one, maybe addAll is copying erroneusly deleted null references?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in multiple threads? `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe. Fundamentally I *suspect* you're misdiagnosing the problem, but it's hard to tell without seeing a repro.

Comment: @JonSkeet Before iterating, and after removing, I'm merging three arrays with "addAll()" into a mixed one, maybe addAll is copying erroneusly deleted null references?

Comment: @JonSkeet btw I'm not using threads, and I deleted the items long before iterating them, so I think it's not a concurrence problem

Comment: Rather than *describing* your code, you should *show* us your code - ideally in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have the error, due you are iterating an object reference, when you delete an object, the reference waits the instance is the same. you can use a hashmap, it permits to iterate and delete object in the same time

An example to get the error that i said

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.generic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> dta = new ArrayList<>();
            dta.add("Prueba");
            dta.add("Prueba 2");
            dta.add("Prueba 3");
            for (String tmp : dta) {
                System.out.println(tmp);
                System.out.println(tmp);
                dta.remove(1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It produces the next error

> cd C:\Users\wilso\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjectsF\OverFlow;
>   "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91" cmd /c
>   "\"\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\"
>   -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.generic.prueba\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe\"
>   -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar\"
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\"" Running NetBeans
>   Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output
>   directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on)
>   will be used instead of their jar artifacts. Scanning for projects...
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Building OverFlow 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ OverFlow --- Prueba Prueba java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)  at
>   com.generic.prueba.main(prueba.java:23)
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD SUCCESS
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 0.748s Finished at: Sun Feb 02 13:55:11 COT 2020 Final
>
> ### Memory: 6M/245M

Comment: Before iterating, and after removing, I'm merging three arrays with "addAll()" into a mixed one, maybe addAll is copying erroneusly deleted null references?

Comment: btw I deleted the items long before iterating them, so I think it's not a concurrence problem

Comment: no sorry, it's an enormous project, but the problem is just iterating a simple array after removing some items, very simple

Comment: remove is called a long time before iterating, in your sample is called in the same for

Comment: have you tried to clone the reference before  iterate?

Comment: what kind of loop are you using?

Comment: @NullPointerException: Just because the actual project is enormous doesn't mean you have to post an enormous amount of code. You should work on reproducing this with minimal code. You may well find the problem while minimizing it, and if you don't, you'll be in a much better position to ask for help.